# numpy.empty() with specific dtype. wrong "shape"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dtype

I'm trying to create a empty array with specific dtypes.

I can create a normal array (with values) but using numpy.empty() returns a wrongly shaped array.

```py
import numpy as np
>>> dt = np.dtype([('exchange', np.unicode_, 16), 
                   ('price', np.float16), 
                   ('size', np.int32)])
```

Now I can create an array with the correct shape and values:

```py
>>> np.array([('me', 1.0, 1)], dtype=dt)
array([('me', 1., 1)],
      dtype=[('exchange', '<U16'), ('price', '<f8'), ('size', '<i4')])
```

This return a (1,) shape, but I need a (1,3) shape.

Using this return error:

```py
>>> np.array(['me', 1., 1], dtype=dt)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'me'
```

But if I try to create a empty array using this dtype, it returns a wrong "shape".

```py
>>> np.empty(shape=(1, 3), dtype=dt)
array([[('', 0., 0), ('', 0., 0), ('', 0., 0)]],
      dtype=[('exchange', '<U16'), ('price', '<f8'), ('size', '<i4')])
```

I expected the result to look like the first example, not the second.
How to do this?

My python version

```py
>>> import sys, numpy; print(numpy.__version__, sys.version)
1.17.0 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 16:52:21) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
```

Comment: ... did you try seeing what `np.array([('me', 1.0, 1)], dtype=dt).shape` is? It's definitely not `(1, 3)`. There is only one item, so it's shape is `(1,)`

Answer (score 0):

Your example [1] is a single element array that contains a 3-elements tuple. To achieve that, you can do:

```
>>> np.empty(1, dtype=dt)
array([('', 0., 0)],
      dtype=[('exchange', '<U16'), ('price', '<f8'), ('size', '<i4')])
```